# How to run auctex mode on emacs 24.3 on ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: emacs, auctex

So I've installed ELPA, and did the command `M-x package-install RET auctex`.
I was prompted with the message that 133 files were compiled and one was skipped.
But I cannot find auctex mode anywhere when trying to initialize it with `M-x auctex-mode`.
Am I missing something?

Comment: yes, but it shows an error on startup that says "File Error: Cannot open load file, auctex.el"

Comment: My bad, you used ELPA and the guide says that you should not put that line in your init file.  Note that AUCTeX modes can be invoked with commands like `M-x TeX-*` or `M-x LaTeX-*`.

Comment: let me try that by removing the mentioned line.

Comment: For example, `M-x LaTeX-math-mode`

Comment: I don't see in the documentation how any of the modes are entered on a regular basis, it seems to be assuming that your file is named `myfile.tex` or something like that, but there's no documentation (that I can find) that shows this.

Comment: yeah, I'm also not sure what mode to use and when, but I think they shall work just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AUCTeX is a package that includes multiple TeX and LaTeX modes, but does not define an explicit `AUCTeX` mode.  To invoke a mode explicitly, use `M-x TeX-<TAB>` or `M-x LaTeX-<TAB>` to see the possibilities.

Assuming that the package is installed correctly, these tab-completions should resolve.

Various of the modes may be started automatically upon opening files with certain extensions, perhaps like `myfile.tex` or similar.